# JPA PersistenceException: Class name could not be resolved

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to create a method to get a project by the project name from GAE, but I'm getting the following error.

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Class name TestProject could not be resolved`

I get this error in the following piece of code on the line where the `if`statement starts

```
public Project getProjectByProjectName(String projectName){
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.projectName = " + projectName);       
    Project p = null;
    if(q.getResultList().size() != 0){
        p = (Project) q.getSingleResult();
    }
    return p;
}
```

I called the method like this: `getProjectByProjectName("TestProject");`

Why does java think that testproject is a class? Is the query wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the project name is `TestProject`, the query should be

```
SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.projectName = 'TestProject'
```

and not, as you are doing

```
SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.projectName = TestProject
```

All that wouldn't happen if you stopped using String concatenation to pass parameters to queries. This makes your code vulnerable to [JPQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). And it will break as soon as a project name contains a single quote. Use parameters:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.projectName = :name");
q.setParameter("name", projectName);
```